# Error About Google Vault API with python program

Tags: google-vault-api

Im using Google Vault API from the python program.
Using method is [Method: matters.exports.create]

reference
https://developers.google.com/vault/reference/rest/v1/matters.exports/create

Using python library is google-api-python-client.
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client

```
result = service.matters().exports().get(matterId=matter_id, exportId=vault_extraction.export_id, alt='json').execute()
```

I executed that python program, and got an API error response.
"<HttpError 400 Request contains an invalid argument>"

I'd like to know why i got the error, and how to resolve this error.

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are talking about `create` but the code that you show is about `get`. Which one it is? Why did you add the other one?

Comment: I'm sorry. I wrote the wrong code. 
I would like to talking about `create`.

the correct code is below.

`result = service.matters().exports().create(matterId=matter_id, body=body).execute()`

thanks.